# What code is generated for Ada Array of Records loop?

Tags: ada

For example for:

```
type PERSONCV is
   record
      name: String ( 1..4 );
      age: Integer;
      cvtext: String ( 1..2000 );
   end record;

N: constant := 40000;
persons : array ( 1..N ) of PERSONCV;

function jobcandidate return Boolean is
   iscandidate: Boolean := False;
begin
   for p of persons loop   -- what code is generated for this?
      if p.age >= 18 then
         iscandidate := true;
         exit;
      end if;
   end loop;
   return iscandidate;
end;
```

In C/C++ the loop part would typically be:

```
PERSONCV * p; // address pointer
int k = 0;
while ( k < N )
   {
   p = &persons [ k ]; // pointer to k'th record
   if ( p->age >= 18 )...  
   ...
   k++ ;
   }
```

I have read that Ada uses Value semantics for records.
Does the Ada loop above copy the k'th record to loop variable p?
e.g. like this is in C/C++ :

```
PERSONCV p; // object/variable
int k = 0;
while ( k < N )
   {
   memcpy ( &p, &persons [ k ], sizeof ( PERSONCV ) ); // copies k'th elem 
   if ( p.age >= 18 )...  
   ...
   k++ ;
   }
```

Comment: Where did you read that Ada uses value semantics for this?

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you are using GNAT, there are two avenues of investigation.

The switch `-gnatG` will regenerate an Ada-like representation of what the front end of the compiler is going to pass to the back end (before any optimisations). In this case, I see

```
   function resander__jobcandidate return boolean is
      iscandidate : boolean := false;
      L_1 : label
   begin
      L_1 : for C8b in 1 .. 40000 loop
         p : resander__personcv renames resander__persons (C8b);
         if p.age >= 18 then
            iscandidate := true;
            exit;
         end if;
      end loop L_1;
      return iscandidate;
   end resander__jobcandidate;
```

so the question is, how does `renames` get translated? Given that the record size is 2008 bytes, the chances of the compiler generating a copy is pretty much zero.

The second investigatory approach is to keep the assembly code that the compiler normally emits to the assembler and then deletes, using the switch `-S`. This confirms that the code generated is like your first C++ version (for macOS).

As an interesting sidelight, Ada 2012 allows an alternate implementation of `jobcandidate`:

```
   function jobcandidate2 return Boolean is
     (for some p of persons => p.age >= 18);
```

which generates identical code.

Comment: I like the alternative implementation!

Comment: See also [*Rationale for Ada 2012, §3.4 Quantified expressions*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rat/html/Rat12-3-4.html).

Comment: The GNAT options helped to fully answer the question. Very useful! Many thanks Simon.

Comment: The RM zeroes the chance of copying (for renaming), I'd think: "a renaming_declaration is an example of a declaration that does not define a new entity, but instead defines a view of an existing entity" [LRM 3.1(7)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-1.html). So, `p` is `resander__persons (C8b)` on every iteration. But this only shifts the question.

Comment: @B98, that must be the case for a `limited` object, but I don’t think you’d be able to tell if a crazy compiler implementer copied an unlimited object?  By the way, the online ARMs for 2012 and later allow you to link to a specific paragraph by appending `#p{paragraph number}` to the page’s URL, in this case `#p7`: [ARM3.1(7)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-1.html#p7).

Comment: @SimonWright, I still think rename may just create a "view" of object preserving all properties, and hence effects of modification. But I have asked for opinions on c.l.ada. `renames` might then be worth an entry in [Ada Docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ada/)? Thanks for the linking tip.

Comment: A somewhat authoritative posting to c.l.ada (<o65pn9$7al$1@franka.jacob-sparre.dk>) states that "Logically, the item is not a copy. How the compiler implements that, however, is its business." (And one would want to stay in business…) Also, respondents refer to cases that preclude referencing, such as packed arrays or items stored in registers.

Answer (score 9):

I suspect that what you have read about Ada is wrong, and probably worse, is encouraging you to think about Ada in the wrong way.

Ada's intent is to encourage thinking in the problem domain, i.e. to specify what should happen, rather than thinking in the solution domain, i.e. to implement the fine details of exactly how.

So here the intent is to loop over all Persons, exit returning True  on meeting the first over 18, otherwise return False.

And that's it.

By and large Ada mandates nothing about the details of how it's done, provided those semantics are satisfied.

Then, the intent is, you just expect the compiler to do the right thing.

Now an individual compiler may choose one implementation over another - or may switch between implementations according to optimisation heuristics, taking into account which CPU it's compiling for, as well as the size of the objects (will they fit into a register?) etc.

You could imagine a CPU with many registers, where a single cache line read makes the copy implementation faster than operating in place (especially if there are no modifications to write back to P's contents), or other target CPUs where the reverse was true. Why would you want to stop the compiler picking the better implementation?

A good example of this is Ada's approach to parameter passing to subprograms - name, value or reference semantics really don't apply - instead, you specify the parameter passing mode - `in`, `out`, or `in out` describing the information flow to (or from) the subprogram. Intuitive, provides semantics that can be more rigorously checked, and leaves the compiler free to pick the best (fastest, smallest, depending on your goal) implementation that correctly obeys those semantics.

Now it would be possible for a specific Ada compiler to make poor choices, and 30 years ago when computers were barely big enough to run an Ada compiler at all, you might well have found performance compromised for simplicity in early releases of a compiler.

But we have thirty more years of compiler development now, running on more powerful computers. So, today, I'd expect the compiler to normally make the best choice. And if you find a specific compiler missing out on performance optimisations, file an enhancement request. Ada compilers aren't perfect, just like any other compiler.

In this specific example, I'd normally expect P to be a cursor into the array, and operations to happen in-place, i.e. reference semantics. Or possibly a hybrid between forms, where one memory fetch into a register serves several operations, like a partial form of value semantics.

If your interest is academic, you can easily look at the assembly output from whatever compiler you're using and find out. Or write all three versions above and benchmark them.

Comment: I have known about Ada for years but never had a chance to use it. Until now. My Ada had gone rusty so I googled and came across several posts (at least one by a university computer science department) stating that Ada uses Value Semantics, not Reference semantics. I found that difficult believe since it would ruin performance for handling large records, especially in loops. So I asked in this forum. I totally agree with everything in your answer. Many thanks Brian.

Answer (score 0):

Using a current compiler (GCC 7.0.0), I have copied your source to both an Ada program and a C++ program, using `std:array<char, 4>` etc. corresponding to `String( 1..4 )` etc. Switches were simply `-O2` for C++, and `-O2 -gnatp` for Ada, so as to use comparable settings regarding checked access to array elements, etc.

These are the results for `jobcandidate`:

C++:

```
    movl    $_ZN15Loop_Over_Array7personsE+4, %eax
    movl    $_ZN15Loop_Over_Array7personsE+80320004, %edx
    jmp .L3
.L8:
    addq    $2008, %rax
    cmpq    %rdx, %rax
    je  .L7
.L3:
    cmpl    $17, (%rax)
    jle .L8
    movl    $1, %eax
    ret
.L7:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    ret
```

Ada:

```
    movl    $1, %eax
    jmp .L5
.L10:
    addq    $1, %rax
    cmpq    $40001, %rax
    je  .L9
.L5:
    imulq   $2008, %rax, %rdx
    cmpl    $17, loop_over_array__persons-2004(%rdx)
    jle .L10
    movl    $1, %eax
    ret
.L9:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    ret
```

One difference I see is in how either implementation uses *%edx* and *%eax*; for going form one element of the array to the next, and testing whether the end has been reached. Ada seems to `imulq` the element size to set the cursor, C++ seems to `addq` it to the pointer.

I haven't measured performance.